# [Digest Auth]: postman or request with custom headers, both ok; python3-requests(2.14.2) failed

Tags: python, python-requests, digest-authentication

I send a POST request to register to my website.

I use PostMan, i get 200 ok

I send the POST request twice myself, use custom headers, i also get 200 ok

When i use python3 package (requests), i get 401.

Here are the steps:

1. I've defined a function to calculate md5 and custom headers:

   > ```
   > import re 
   > import hashlib
   >
   > def md5_utf8(x):
   >     if isinstance(x, str):
   >         x = x.encode('utf-8')
   >     return hashlib.md5(x).hexdigest()
   >
   >
   > def make_digest_auth_headers(my_auth, uri):
   >     nonce = re.findall(r'nonce="(.*?)"', my_auth)[0]
   >     realm = re.findall(r'realm="(.*?)"', my_auth)[0]
   >     qop = re.findall(r'qop="(.*?)"', my_auth)[0]
   >
   >     uri = uri
   >     method = "POST"
   >     nc = "00000001"
   >     cnonce = "0a4f113b"
   >     username = "my_user"
   >     pwd = "my_pwd"
   >     # cal HA1
   >     HA1 = md5_utf8(username + ":" + realm + ":" + pwd)
   >     # cal HA2
   >     HA2 = md5_utf8(method + ":" + uri)
   >     # cal client response
   >     response = md5_utf8(HA1 + ":" + nonce + ":" + nc + ":" + cnonce + ":" + qop + ":" + HA2)
   >
   >     headers = {
   >         "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
   >         "HOST": "ip:port",
   >         "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
   >         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
   >         "Connection": "keep-alive",
   >         "cache-control": "no-cache",
   >         "Authorization": 'Digest username="' + username + '", realm="' + realm
   >                          + '", nonce="' + nonce + '", uri="' + uri
   >                          + '", algorithm=MD5, response="' + response + '", qop='
   >                          + qop + ', nc=' + nc + ', cnonce="' + cnonce + '"'
   >     }
   >
   >     return headers
   > ```
2. I sent a POST request like this.

> ```
> import requests
> session = requests.Session()
> session.headers = {
>                 "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
>                 "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
>             }
>
> uri = "/System/Register"
>
> data = {
>             "RegisterObject": {
>                 "DeviceID": my_id
>             }
>         }
>
> r = session.post('http://my_ip:my_port/System/Register', json=data)
> headers = make_digest_auth_headers(r.headers['WWW-Authenticate'], uri)
> r = self.session.post(f'{url}/VIID/System/Register', json=data, headers=headers)
> print(r.json())
> ```

3. I got 200 ok response

> ```
> {'ResponseStatusObject': {'Id': 'my_id',
>                           'LocalTime': '20190122090110',
>                           'RequestURL': 'http://ip:port/System/Register',
>                           'StatusCode': 0,
>                           'StatusString': 'OK'}}
> ```

4. I use python3-requests:

> ```
> import requests
> from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
>
> session = requests.Session()
> session.auth = HTTPDigestAuth(my_user, my_pwd)
> session.headers = {
>             "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
>             "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
>         }
>
> data = {
>             "RegisterObject": {
>                 "DeviceID": my_id
>             }
>         }
> session.post('http://ip:port/System/Register', json=data)
> ```

5. I got 401:

> ```
> {'ResponseStatusObject': {'Id': 'my_id',
>                           'LocalTime': '20190122090110',
>                           'RequestURL': 'http://ip:port/System/Register',
>                           'StatusCode': 104,
>                           'StatusString': 'Failed'}}
> ```

I don't know why? so strange.
Thanks.

Comment: Error 401 is for unauthorized users  HttpDigestUser is not authorised and you didn't add www-authenticate to header either

Comment: Thanks. As i know, requests(python3) do the digest auth itself. `session.auth = HTTPDigestAuth(my_user, my_pwd)` There is no need to add www-authenticate to headers manually.